# Unicode filenames as parameters in Command Prompt

Tags: cygwin, librsync

I am successfully using rdiff.exe and cygwin1.dll to create signatures from command prompt.
My Problem is that with Unicode files it is not working?

rdiff -b 10240 signature "ฉันเจ็บ.txt" "ฉันเจ็บ.sig"

I am using Windows7.

Comment: it works for me. What is your LANG setting ?

Comment: Lang is set to English. I am a developer and I will be distributing to customers. Can't ask them to setup lang settings. Also it is visible in Windows. Only problem is via command prompt

Comment: have you tried from Bash ?.With `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` it works for me

Comment: I downloaded bash from win-bash.sourceforge.net and in the bash$ I gave the command LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and next I gave the bat file. But result was that the file name which showed as ????? now showed the ASCII values all the same Rdiff could not find the file.

Comment: adding this line at the start of the Bat file did the trick: chcp 65001, Also needed the correct Cygwin.dll

Comment: as Bash I mean the cygwin one.